# Ruby application fails to connect to IMAP server on port 993

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, imap, mail-server

I have a mail server to which I'm connecting from a ruby application using protocol IMAP.
But I get an error in rails console:

```
Loading dev environment (Rails 7.0.4)
irb(main):001:0> @connection = Net::IMAP.new('mail.test.com.test', 993, true)

Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):1
        1: from (irb):1:in `new'
Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect)
```

Vesrions used:

```
rails: 7.0.4 
ruby: ruby 2.7.3p183
```

So I started testing with OpenSSL over implicit port `993` and recieved error:

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.test.com.test:993 


CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 319 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

But it seems that the IMAP connection over an explicit port `143` with TLS works fine:

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.test.com.test:143 -starttls imap -brief


CONNECTION ESTABLISHED
Protocol version: TLSv1.2
Ciphersuite: <suite>
Peer certificate: CN = mail.test.com.test
Hash used: SHA256
Signature type: RSA
Verification: OK
Server Temp Key: <key>, P-384, 384 bits
. OK CAPABILITY completed.
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This is a mail server configuration problem. This question requires your mail server config and should be moved to Super User.

Comment: Okay, I'll move this question to Super User.

Comment: I meant Server Fault